# Why is the package body not showing all objects in sqldeveloper?

Tags: package, oracle-sqldeveloper

I came across this issue that a package in sqldeveloper, which is in regular use, appears with a gappy list of functions and procedures in the body but they are correctly displayed in the spec in sqldeveloper. There is also an object in the package body called `gc_package_name` (see screenshot). I assume this latter object might be due to a software we installed which does version controlling of the objects.

I tried refreshing the packages, reconnecting to the schema and also right click on the spec and navigate. I can see all functions and procedures in the actual package body but some are not listed on the left hand side. See an example of the functions not shown in the body highlighted in the screenshot.

My sqldeveloper versions is 20.4.

The package has been compiled and it shows no errors.

Anyone has an idea what might be the reason for this?

[image: Example missing function highlighted]

Comment: Your version of sqldev is like 8 years old

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Should have added that we have similar issues across a few developers, the sqldeveloper I'm using daily is on 18.4. I've edited the post, thanks for noticing.

Comment: How about sharing the source of one of these packages

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I have amended my post, with my sqldeveloper now updated to the latest available version. I cannot post the actual source as it's company confidential, but I shared the full spec and body object list from the left pane.

Comment: Without a test case I can't help you